# Keep logged in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, cordova

I'm developing my first mobile application using jquery mobile and phoneGap to build my application on the different operating system for mobile and i'm blocked on how to keep the users logged in once they enter their information of authentication the first time

Can you share with me your propositions i read some subject on how to keep logged in by using cookies for the browsers and now i need a solution for mobile application

thank you in advance friends

Answer (score 0):

**localStorage** allows permanent storage,

```
window.localStorage.key = value;    
To get the value, Use this;
var value = window.localStorage.key;
```

**sessionStorage** allows storage in the session.

```
window.sessionStorage.key=value;
To get the value, Use this;
var value = window.sessionStorge.key;
```

See the [Link](http://he-jquerymobile-tutorial.org/jquery-mobile-tutorial-CH22.php)

OR use the Local Data Base to store the data at client side.

```
var dbShell = window.openDatabase(name, version, display_name, size);
```

in Device Ready Function create the data base

```
var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);


function populateDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}

db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```

PhoneGap [Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html)

Refer These Links for More Info

[IndexDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)

[HTML5 Storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage)

Comment: thank you and how can i read this informations from the localStorage later.when the user try to connect to my application an other time ??

Comment: use var userName = window.localStorage.name you will get the user name